# In xaml/c# coding, text box buttons keep getting cut off?

Tags: c#, xaml

I've done a google search already and many people have said to remove all the height/width/margin properties, but this doesn't seem to work for the text boxes where you enter the binary value and the decimal value. Right now everything will resize accordingly if you drag the window, but the buttons will still cut out sometimes.

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Binary to Decimal Converter" FontSize="25" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="binaryValue" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" BorderThickness="1" FontSize="20" TextChanged="binaryValue_TextChanged" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Padding="0" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="decimalValue" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" BorderThickness="1" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Times New Roman" TextChanged="decimalValue_TextChanged" Padding="0" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockBin" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Binary Value:" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="16" Margin="0,0,0,14"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockDec" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Decimal Value:" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="16" Margin="0,0,0,14"/>
        <Button x:Name="buttonConvert" Content="Convert!" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: try removing `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"`, but leave the `vertical` one there - does that help?

Comment: @simonalexander2005 no, the text field boxes are still cutting off

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes because you are using `*` (relative sizes) for your column heights and widths.

Because your text is a fixed size, it would be better to give the columns and rows a fixed size also in those cases. Then you can use `*` for the edges, so that it scales around the text.

Alternatively, you can use `Auto`.

For example:

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

You can then give the Page a `minwidth` and `minheight` to prevent it shrinking smaller than the content.